# Accesing values of another program

Tags: c++, windows, reverse-engineering

So, I've been wondering that how I access values of different program with my c++ code.

I understand that I have to know the memory location and access it somehow but I don't really know how.

Let's say that I have a game where I have a character that has a certain amount of health and I want to read that health with my c++ code (similar to how you can read different values with the cheat engine program).

How would I accomplish this?

For clarity: Operating system is windows

Comment: You should look into **shared memory**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (safer than ReadProcessMemory) and [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  functions.

If you are clever you can inject a DLL, then you can use pointers in your code

```
int * money = 0x00400000+0x00ABCDEF;//pointer to money address
*money = 5000;//set money to 5000.
```

if you need DLL examples, here are some:

[Red Alert 3 Player Information Mod](https://gpb.googlecode.com/files/RA3INFOMOD.zip)

[Need for Speed: Underground 2 cheat mod](https://gpb.googlecode.com/files/NFSMOD.0.4.9.zip)

Sometimes pointers can change what they point to, this can be "dangerous" in terms of the application.

When you access a pointer which points to a protected memory area, inaccessible memory, not to the stuff you want or an invalid location your application may crash. I don't know how Cheat Engine prevents it but you have a few options, the ones I suggest:

- Exit application gracefully and let the user know you couldn't handle it
- Handle the problem with a try / catch block instead? (be sure to capture the correct error)
- Hard exit the application
- Do nothing and let the application behave weird / crash
- ... more and more

I also wrote pointer class myself which handles the dereferencing and stops when an error is encountered (returns null)

```
//null as last parameter automaticly "Dereferences"
template<class T = DWORD, class S = DWORD> struct Pointer
{
private:
    std::vector<S> params;
    S variable;
    bool MoreThanOne;
public:
    //null as last parameter automaticly "Dereferences"
    template<class... Args> 
    Pointer(Args... args) 
    {  
        std::array<S, sizeof...(args)> list = {args...};
        for( auto i : list)
            params.push_back(i);
        if(params.size() > 1)
            MoreThanOne = true;
        else
            MoreThanOne = false;
    }
    T ResolvePointer() 
    {  
        variable = params[0];
        if(!MoreThanOne)
            return (T)variable;
        try
        {
            auto it = params.begin();
            ++it;  
            for(; it != params.end(); ++it)
            {
                if(*reinterpret_cast<S*>(variable) == NULL)
                    return static_cast<T>(NULL);
                variable = *reinterpret_cast<S*>(variable) + *it;
            }
        }
        catch(...)
        {   
            return static_cast<T>(NULL);
        }
        return (T)variable;
    }
    T operator()()
    {
        return ResolvePointer();
    }
};
```

usage:

```
unsigned long ipaddr = htonl(Pointer<unsigned long>(0x00400000+0x008E3A74,0x04,0x38,NULL)());//pointer to players IP address
if(ipaddr != NULL)//....
```

Comment: There are usually other precautions that should be taken with this method.

Comment: Wow. That's ridiculous that these things work - does the process being attached to need to go out of its way to expose access like that?

Comment: @RonDahlgren, There's not a whole lot you can do about DLL injection. I believe it can't happen with an underprivileged token. It's interesting to play around with at least. Do recall that many hooks use DLL injection.

Comment: I haven't looked into it for quite some time, and didn't do a lot when I was, but there's some `QueryBlahBlahBlah` function that, possibly among others, aids in making sure the memory is valid. I'm not sure if Cheat Engine's scan feature is more clever than a combination of these functions and every possible address, though.

Comment: Ah yes, [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Well how do things like the unofficial GTA san andread multiplayer and mafia 2 multiplayer work as they need to access the data in the game and they can even modify it. How do they make sure that the memory is valid?

Comment: As for those Games communities have been developing applications over years, hacking and decompiling, disasembling etc. If you have enough information about an application you can reconstruct headers which really can help to call functions instead of playing with pointers. [See it yourself - MTA is open-source](https://code.google.com/p/mtasa-blue/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FMTA10%2Fmultiplayer_sa)
 Quick example, you know that the function "sub_4858273" - random number - is something like SetVehicleColor, you can call that from a DLL too. executing functions can be done too by executing adrs

Answer (score 0):

You should not write to another process's memory space without using specific [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanisms. Operating systems typically prevent this for obvious reasons. Instead, you would need to use the target application's extension mechanisms, or decompile / modify / hex edit to effect the changes you want. That being said, doing so may be in violation of the terms of service for the software you are messing with.

To be clear, the code will compile just fine, letting you set a pointer to whatever arbitrary address you'd like, but once you try to read or write that address, the OS will step in and cause an error condition.

If you aren't violating the software's [EULA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) by doing so, here are some pointers for finding things you might like to modify:

- If the code can be decompiled into some readable source form, do so and make modifications there.
- Edit the compiled binary with a hex editor, look for well-defined values and change them (does the max_health always start out at 25? That might be unique enough to locate and modify). A note about this: Make sure the values you intend to insert fit in the same space as the original values, otherwise you will break things and have undefined results.
- Does the application provide an extension mechanism, such as a scripting API or mod support? If so, this can be a vector for causing the types of system changes you want.

Comment: I edited my first post, reading the value is fine. I don't really need to write to it.

Comment: @Ron How then does a program such as [this](http://www.artmoney.ru/) work? I've used it in the past to locate/view/modify values in arbitrary processes.

Comment: Huh, I guess whatever version of Windows that works on doesn't offer these basic memory protections. Make that one more reason to stay far, far away from that platform :-)

Comment: @Ron It claims to work on all versions of Windows from 95 onwards. I can vouch for it working on XP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access variables in another process unless:

1. Your program uses "debug functions" to access the values.
2. You use some sort of IPC (shared memory, pipes, message queues) to share/transfer the data.

Each process has its own address space [1], and there is no way to access into another process's address space without some mechanism to access it.

[1] Assuming we're talking about a "real" OS that uses proper memory management. In some OS's such as traditional DOS, there is no memory protection between processes. But no sane person works with these OS's unless the system is running with a very feeble processor and small amounts of memory.

Comment: OP stated he uses Windows.

Comment: Yes, and if I'd not put my footnote there, someone would have pointed out that some other OS's (like DOS) doesn't have memory protection.

Comment: @Mats How then does a program such as [this](http://www.artmoney.ru/) work? I've used it in the past to locate/view/modify values in arbitrary processes.

Comment: I expect it used debug functions - same as "WinDBG" or Visual Studio's Debugger functions. I have used (and even written) debuggers, but I've not used anything like what you've linked, much less analyzed what these products do. I don't play games - and I certainly wouldn't cheat in one.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, But the fun is in working hard and slowly getting through your errors to a point where your cheating works, not the cheating itself ;) Different games take different measures against this sort of thing anyway. Of course the game's no fun when you cheat through it, though.